# Fix Picamera in Python MMAL Error Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

I've tried many tutorials and installation to use the rapsberry 4 picamera with Python I'm using Picamera library and everytime I use this simple script or any picamera script to try the camera I got this error message:

```
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not find component 'vc.camera_info'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/ex.py", line 6, in <module>
    camera = PiCamera()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv450/lib/python3.9/site-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 367, in __init__
    with mo.MMALCameraInfo() as camera_info:
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv450/lib/python3.9/site-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2346, in __init__
    super(MMALCameraInfo, self).__init__()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv450/lib/python3.9/site-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 631, in __init__
    mmal_check(
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv450/lib/python3.9/site-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to create MMAL component b'vc.camera_info': Function not implemented
```

The code I used is:

```
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.start_preview()
sleep(2)
camera.capture('foo.jpg')
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There could be any number of reasons... you may have failed to configure something in `raspi-config`, you may have tinkered with the GPU memory split in `config.txt`, you may have permissions issues, you may have a software conflict/incompatibility.

I think you are going to need to do some old-fashioned sleuthing. I would:

- try taking a picture with built-in `raspistill` to be sure your camera and cabling and hardware are correct
- try removing and reinstalling or updating PiCamera package
- try being more explicit about using specifically Python3 with a shebang
- try using different camera and/or cable and/or Raspberry Pi
- try making a separate fresh installation of Raspberry Pi OS